# how to reload a selected node of a tree

Tags: tree, extjs4, reload, treenode

I need to reload a tree after deleting one of the leafs of a node. The problem of reloading the entire store is, it's too slow. That's why I just want to reload a node where its leaf is deleted.

I tried this.. but it says null...

```
Ext.getCmp('myTree').root.reload();
```

I also tried

```
var tempParent = Ext.getCmp('myTree').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].parentNode;
Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('myStore').load( {node: tempParent});
```

this doesn't help either...
Does anyone have similar issues that's been solved?

**Update**

```
var node = Ext.getCmp('myTree').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].parentNode.get('id');
```

this does give me the parent node...
but When I load it

```
Ext.getCmp('myTree').store.load({ node: node });
```

I get this error

> TypeError: b.getId is not a function

**Second Update--**

This is what my tree looks like

- 1st Node

  - 1st Leaf
- 2nd Node

  - 1st Leaf

Now when I delete the 1st Leaf of the 2nd Node... the 1st Node appears under 2nd Node

- 1st Node

  - 1st Leaf
- 2nd Node

  - 1st Node

Comment: Is the tree bound to a store? Could you give a bit more information on why you need to reload the parent node? ExtJs would generally handle this correctly without you having to do anything.

Comment: Thanks Izhaki... I have a delete leaf function on my tree... and there can be multiple same leafs(let's say there can be 2 'leaf1')... so when I delete on 'leaf1', only the selected 'leaf1' gets deleted.. the second 'leaf1' is still on the tree... but when I manually refresh the browser, it's gone

Comment: And can't you just listen for node removal; find related nodes; and delete them as well?

Comment: That's exactly that I am trying to do... find related nodes... and I can't seem to wrap my head around it... could you please show me some samples

Comment: I updated my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to refresh a specific node of a tree. In your case you may want to refresh a parent node under which changes need to be shown:

```
   refreshRow:function(id){
        var node = this.store.getNodeById(id);
        if (node){
            this.store.load({node:node});
        }
     }
```

**Update**

Based on the information you provided my conclusion is that you are trying to populate the same Node with a specific server generated ID in several places in a Tree. The tree store does not support this. Each node must have a unique ID even if the the rest of the Node information is the same.

Comment: Thanks dbrin... is this refreshRow inside beforedrop config? because I tried to do it after an ajax failure fn and it says getNodeyByid is not a function

Comment: probably because ajax callback is in windows scope. Change the code to get a reference to the store of the tree panel.

Comment: Yes Dbrin.. I used Ext.getCmp.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].getNodeById(id) and I still get the same error... however doing parentNode.get('id') works. it gives me the node but it says TypeError: b.getId is not a function on load

Comment: getNodeById is a function on the store :: store.getNodeById(id);

Comment: Well... :)... now it refreshes the node but then loads the first node of the tree on that node where the delete was done... and I also get this error TypeError: a[b] is undefined

Comment: sorry i didn't follow that. there are probably other issues.  The code above is tested and works in production.

Comment: dbrin... please see my 2nd update... it seems to work but why does my first node of the tree shows up on that node